# Can std::byte replace std::aligned_storage?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, byte, std-byte

C++17 introduced a new type, `std::byte`, so now we finally have a first-class citizen type to represent bytes in memory. Besides being a novelty in the standard,  the C++ rules for object creation, start and end of life, aliasing etc. are fairly complicated an unintuitive most of the times, so whenever I feel `std::byte` is the right tool I also get nervous and reluctant to use it, for fear of unintentionally summoning the Undefined Behavior Balrogs.

One such case is a buffer to be used with placement new:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

struct X { double dummy[4]; char c; };

auto t1()
{
    // the old way

    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(X)> buffer;
    X* x = new (&buffer) X{};

    x->~X();
}

auto t2()
{
    // the new way?

    std::byte buffer[sizeof(X)];
    X* x = new (&buffer) X{};

    x->~X();
}
```

Is `t2` perfectly safe and equivalent with `t1`?

In response to alignment issues, what about:

```
auto t3()
{
    alignas(X) std::byte buffer[sizeof(X)];

    X* x = new (&buffer) X{};
    x->~X();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is `t2` perfectly safe and equivalent with `t1`?

No. In fact, both are bad.

`t2` is bad for the reason [NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58288283/2069064) indicates: it's underaligned. You'd need to write:

```
alignas(X) std::byte storage[sizeof(X)];
```

`t1` also kind of has this problem, in that you almost certainly want to write `aligned_storage_t<sizeof(X), alignof(X)>` and not just `aligned_storage_t<sizeof(X)>`. If `X` were overaligned, you would lose that here. If `X` was just large but had no alignment requirement, you would end up with a relatively overaligned storage.

`t1` is also bad for an especially peculiar reason: `aligned_storage` doesn't quite guarantee what you think it guarantees. In particular, it guarantees that an `X` can fit in `aligned_storage<sizeof(X)>`, but it does not guarantee that it can fit *exactly*. The [specification](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta.trans.other#lib:aligned_storage) is simply:

> The member typedef `type` shall be a trivial standard-layout type suitable for use as uninitialized storage for any object whose size is at most `Len` and whose alignment is a divisor of Align.

That is, `aligned_storage<16>::type` is guaranteed to be at least 16 bytes, but a conforming implementation could easily give you 32. Or 4K. That in addition to the problem of using `aligned_storage<16>` by accident instead of `aligned_storage_t<16>`.

This is why [P1413](https://wg21.link/p1413) exists as a paper: `aligned_storage` is kind of bad.

---

So the real answer is actually just to write something like libstdc++'s [`__aligned_membuf`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/aligned_buffer.h#L46-L78):

```
template <typename T>
struct storage_for {
    alignas(T) std::byte data[sizeof(T)];

    // some useful constructors and stuff, probably some getter
    // that gives you a T* or a T const*
};
```

Answer (score 5):

> Is `t2` perfectly safe and equivalent with `t1`?

No.  `std::aligned_storage` creates storage that is suitably aligned for the object being placed in it.  `std::byte buffer[sizeof(X)]` while being the correct size, has the alignment of `std::byte`.  This normally will not have same alignment of the type you are placing in it since it has an alignment of `1`.

This is not an issue as far as the C++ virtual machine is concerned, but in the real world this can cause sever performance penalties or even cause the program to crash.

If you want suitably aligned storage, <strike>use `std::aligned_storage`</strike> see [Barry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58288603/4342498)

Comment: spitballing here: what about `alignas(alignof(X)) std::byte buffer[sizeof(X)];`?

Comment: @bolov That would be fine then.  That's a lot more typing than `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(X)> buffer` though.

Comment: @NathanOliver: But it would be potentially better, since `alignof(X)` may be far less than the default alignment that `aligned_storage` gives you without specifying an alignment.

Comment: @NicolBolas For that you can use `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(X), alignof(X)> buffer`

Comment: Although now the characters to type is about the same.  I still like it though as the name gives it context and meaning.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Also, `aligned_storage/union` [are being deprecated](https://wg21.link/P1413) in C++20 or 23.

Comment: @NicolBolas Are you sure they are going to be?  I see there is a paper requesting it but it is not part of C++20 (yet) and not all papers are actually accepted.  This seems like it would be a large breaking change for not much or any gain.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Deprecation, by definition, is not a breaking change; it's a declaration of the *intent* to remove in the future. It may not be part of C++20, but given that it was forwarded with near-unanimous votes to LEWG, that seems like a good sign that it's going to happen sooner or later.

Comment: @NicolBolas Okay.  Thanks for the information.  Guess I'll have to stop suggesting it.