# How to replace aligned_storage<T[]> with std::byte[]?

Tags: c++, alignas

The use of `aligned_storage` is deprecated in C++23 and suggested to be replaced with an aligned `std::byte[]` (see [here](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1413r3.pdf)). I have two questions about this:

**1. How to align this?**

The document suggests to replace

`std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> t_buff;` with

`alignas(T) std::byte t_buff[sizeof(T)]`.

However, I am actually storing an array of T (or T is an array of something).
Can I simply replace
`std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> data_[SIZE];` with

`alignas(alignof(T)*SIZE) std::byte data_[sizeof(T) * SIZE];` ?

I think this is a wrong usage of `alignas` or not?

**2. How to read/write?**

I think access has not changed much, so is it correct to read with:

```
reference data(size_t index) noexcept {
    return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data_[index*sizeof(T)]));
}
```

and write with

`new (reinterpret_cast<void*>(&data_[size_*sizeof(T)])) T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};` ?

**Why am I asking?**

My use of `alignas` seems really wrong, how should I align it? Can I really just multiply access index with `sizeof(T)`, or do I need take padding into account? How?

Also, the code somehow seems worse than before because I have to insert `sizeof()` everywhere.

It seems to work when I run it but I am not sure whether this is really save.

I looked at other examples (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58288225/can-stdbyte-replace-stdaligned-storage), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058850/how-to-align-stdarray-contained-data) and others) but they always have `T` instead of `T[]` as an example.

Comment: Why not use `alignas(T[SIZE]) std::byte t_buff[sizeof(T[SIZE])]`?

Comment: @NathanOliver make that an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to do anything different.  Per [[expr.alignof]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.alignof#3) the alignement of `T[N]` is the alignment of `T` so you can just use

```
alignas(T) std::byte data_[sizeof(T) * SIZE];
```

You could also just use the alignment and size of the array iteself like

```
alignas(T[SIZE]) std::byte t_buff[sizeof(T[SIZE])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> data_[SIZE]`. The document suggests replacing the aligned storage with an array, so you get a multidimensional array:

```cpp
    alignas(T) std::byte data_[SIZE][sizeof(T)];
```

And this should be accessed about the same as your previous array of aligned_storage.

You can also make this a single-dimensional array `alignas(T) std::byte data_[SIZE*sizeof(T)]`, but there's not much benefit (as you noted, you need `&data_[i*sizeof(V)]` to get a pointer to the ith element, where with the multidimensional array you can use `data_[i]`)

Comment: I'd prefer a 1D array. Rules for multidimensional arrays are wonky. Depending on how you form a pointer to it, you may or may not be only allowed to index the first sub-array.

Comment: @Artyer Thanks, interesting suggestion but I'll go with a 1D array.